# significance of .Values.nameOverride while declaring cassandra.name in helper template

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I was reviewing helm template on git repo https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/cassandra
for deploying cassandra in Kubernetes.

I can see in helper template file `"_helpers.tpl"` , "cassandra.name" has been defined as below , as I can understand whose default value set to name of the Chart , but why .Values.nameOverride used here , without any pipe (just after `.Chart.Name`) , what is the significant of the same ,I am confused here .

```
{{- define "cassandra.name" -}}
{{- default .Chart.Name .Values.nameOverride | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" -}}
{{- end -}}
```

which is  used in cassandra/template/configmap.yaml as below

```
{{- if .Values.configOverrides }}
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: {{ template "cassandra.name" . }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "cassandra.name" . }}
    chart: {{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
data:
{{ toYaml .Values.configOverrides | indent 2 }}
{{- end }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sprig `default` function](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/defaults.html) takes two parameters, that's why there is no pipe.

If `.Values.nameOverride` is *empty*, `.Chart.Name` will be used.